# Amazon Lex and Amazon Connect Voice Recognition Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, aws-lex, amazon-connect

I have developed a bot in lex and created 3 intents with it. The first intent is to create an incident in a service now platform. I have tested it in lex console. it was working perfectly fine. Now i have created an amazon connect instance and created a contact flow and added these intents to the contact flow. When i tested it with the soft phone. Below are the issues i faced.

1. The prompt plays what things it can do. I have asked it to create an incident. It doesn't understand my voice and keeps on asking "could you please repeat that". After four to five times it understands my intent and prompt me with the questions to create an incident.
2. My intent has two slots which collects incident description and urgency and my employee ID. When i say the incident description, the values are not getting captured properly and in the backend where a tickets gets created i don't see the description which i said.
3. If i say my employee id, it doesn't recognize it properly and takes some random number

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you add lambda function is added to your amazon connect instance as well as LEX.
- If you are using the service now trail version, make sure you wake
  the instance and keep it live.
- make sure you have 'create an incident' utterance in the intent.
- To capture the free text use 'AMAZON.Organization' Built in slot.
- Use AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER or AMAZON.Number for capturing your
  employee ID.

**Note:** It depends on the way you spell it. It's not that easy to capture the number through connect, numbers like five and six should be properly pronounced. Add similar utterance like 'create incident', 'can I create an incident' so that it  invokes intent easily.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have created the similar utterance which you have said. I tried using connect again .. still the same problem. I have another question . For Alphanumeric which slot type we need to use.. Could you please assist.

Comment: if you have a database, then you can actually create a custom slot and push all the alphanumeric values into the slot. Attach the screenshot of your cloudwatch logs.